# Spring Integration Control Bus configuration via annotations

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-integration

**Just a simple question:**
Is there any way to configure [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) Control Bus via annotations (without any xml)

```
<control-bus input-channel="operationChannel"/>
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "controlBusChannel")
public ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus() throws Exception {
    ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus = new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
    return controlBus;
}
```

Note that any `outputChannel` on the annotation will be ignored; it is defined on the bus itself.

Typically the output channel of a control bus is omitted with the result of normal request/reply operations, such as `@someBean.isRunning()` (if someBean implements `Lifecycle` for example) going back to the `replyChannel` header (e.g. to a `MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive()` operation or a Messaging Gateway).

If you need to send the control bus operation results some place else, add an output channel to the factory bean.

Any `MessageHandler` `@Bean` (or a factory bean that creates one) can now be annotated with `@ServiceActivator`. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15188).

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/control-bus/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/controlbus/ControlBusDemoTest.java looks like the second log message is incorrect. Please, check

Comment: How to get result of control bus operation? which operations are available ?

Comment: Don't comment on old answers (nearly 5 years old). Ask a new question.

Comment: @Gary Russell, SO doesn't notify me if you don'e mention my nickname with @ ad symbol

Answer (score 9):

The [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) provides the stuff on the matter:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
     return IntegrationFlows.from("operationChannel").controlBus().get();
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to configure control bus using only [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) ?

Comment: could you tell how to auto wire this to another beans, and will this solution work with custom scoped beans?

Comment: Please, be more specific. And it maybe be better to start a new SO question anyway.

Comment: It uses expression language by default Is there way to customuze it ?

Comment: Well, you can't customize exactly this one, but there is a `GroovyCommandMessageProcessor` as another sample. Essentially, you can implement any custom `MessageProcessor` and perform commands based on the massage any possible way.

Comment: I started to investigate https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/barrier and I am afraid I don't understan what is going on inside https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/barrier/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/server-context.xml. Is it possible to ask you about what is going on? I can't ask here because it is not SO format.

Comment: You can ask on Gitter: https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-integration