# How to programmatically create a Spring FtpOutboundChannelAdapter?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I have a spring boot application and am trying to stick with a Java-only configuration.  Don't ask me yet about the pros vs cons of this approach.  I just don't want to split the configuration across Java and XML.  I'm using Spring Integration and trying to send a file via FTP. In the XML world it would look like

```
<int:channel id="pickupChannel"/>

<bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
   class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory"> ... />

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutputChannel"
        channel="pickupChannel" 
        session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" ...  />
```

I can create the DefaultFtpSessionFactory without too much trouble but **I can't find the class to instantiate for the FtpOutboundChannelAdapter.  That adapter class doesn't seem to exist.**  The closest I can find is FtpOutboundChannelAdapterParser.  But this is looking for some XML to parse.  What's the underlying class to instantiate here?  Am I missing something?  It seems like Spring is looking for an XML-defined bean.  Is spring-boot not yet ready for this Spring Integration beans?

Any help is appreciated.
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849211/spring-integration-control-bus-configuration-via-annotations/27850695#27850695). Since version 4.0 any `MessageHandler` can be configured using `@ServiceActivator`.

In this case, the handler is a `FileTransferringMessageHandler` and it needs to be configured with an appropriately configured `FtpRemoteFileTemplate`.

Which needs a session factory.

`pickupChannel` would be a `DirectChannel`.

**EDIT**:

You should also take a look a the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) which has first class support for FTP. Take a look at the [reference docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference).

Specifically, see [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/ftp/FtpTests.java#L224).

Comment: Also see the java DSL (I edited the answer with links).

Comment: The new Java DSL to the integration project is very interesting and promising.  However, it looks like it does not yet support an SCP channel adapter.  I didn't mention it in my question, but I need to SCP and FTP outbound support.  If this is the case, does this mean my only option is to use the @ServiceActivator annotation?  I suspect that is the way to go -a shame the DSL isn't full featured yet.  Between your two possible solutions I think I found an answer to my question.  Thanks!

Comment: I just realized Spring Integration doesn't handle SCP.  I'm not sure how I missed that.  Since my volume is light and requirements uncomplicated, I just went with Ant Scp.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to follow up on this but got side-tracked because I was traveling. Right, we don't currently have SCP support. Any external integration can easily be wrapped in a POJO and invoked via a `<service-ativator/>`. Feel free to open a new feature JIRA issue.